# How to count characters

Tags: hadoop

I have few text files and I'm looking to count characters in those files but not all the characters. I have to only count how many times letter a, b and c have occurred in those files. I'm very new to Pig. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: It would be good to know what you have tried.
The input , and the expected output, for quicker help .

Answer (score 0):

Load all the files using wildcard character * into field of type chararray.Split the line into words and then into letters and count them.

```
A = LOAD '/path/text*.txt' AS (lines:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE((chararray)lines)) AS words;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(REPLACE(words,'','|'), '|')) AS letters;
D = FILTER C BY (letters matches '.*(a|b|c).*');
E = GROUP D BY letters;
F = FOREACH E GENERATE group,COUNT(D);
DUMP F;
```